# How to get rid of name error: name not defined

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this:

```py
def image(version):
    if version == 'A':
        colour == 'red'
    elif version == 'B':
        colour == 'green'
    else:
        colour == 'yellow'
    print(colour)

        
image('A')
```

I am getting this error: `NameError: name 'colour' is not defined`

Comment: Like the error says, the variable colour has not been initialized. Initialize it at the top with `colour=None`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the comparison operator (`==`) when you should be using the assignment operator (`=`). The statements inside the `if`, `elif`, and `else` all attempt to compare `colour` with a string value. But, since `colour` is not defined, a `NameError` is raised.

```py
def image(version):
    if version == 'A':
        colour = 'red'
    elif version == 'B':
        colour = 'green'
    else:
        colour = 'yellow'
    print(colour)


image('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `colour == ...` which is simply testing for equality, not storing a value.

In each of those if statements use a single `=` which will assign the value to `colour`. E.g.:

```
def image(version):
    if version == 'A':
        colour = 'red'
    elif version == 'B':
        colour = 'green'
    else:
        colour = 'yellow'
    print(colour)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the return statement and change your "colour ==" to color = because you're assigning a variable not comparing it.

```py
def image(version):
    if version == 'A':
        colour = 'red'
    elif version == 'B':
        colour = 'green'
    else:
        colour = 'yellow'
    return(colour)

 
print(image('A'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the colour to 'red', 'green', or 'yellow' using = instead of comparing them using ==.

```
colour = 'red'
```